# How to remove demo content from a theme

Tags: database, wordpress

I currently run a VPS and have had no problems with one of the themes I run.  I have now added an additional domain.  With this domain, I have utilised a new theme but it is sluggish.  In fact, it takes over 60 seconds to load a page.  I have tried all the usuals; caching, minifying etc but has little effect.  In fact, the caching increased the page load speed by 5 seconds.

With this theme, there are a further 20+ themes included where I can import the demo content.  I have thought that maybe the content for all of this demo content may play a part.  Of course, I may be wrong but would like to eliminate this as an option.

With this in mind, does anyone know if it is fairly easy to delete the demo content from a theme and if so, where could I find this, using filezilla?  As a side note, I have visited the theme folder but it only displays the 'parent theme' and not the individual themes/demo content.

Any help on this matter, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Craig
p.s I have tried contacting the theme developer but they have not responded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well because the demo content is saved within your database. So you won't find anything from the FTP.

Furthermore, if it's not installed, the installable demo packages are *most of the time* loaded remotely from the theme's author server. Otherwise you package would be very very heavy.

So if you've already installed it. There is now way to remove it in one shot if you already had some content before as your database has been affected (posts tables, options table, metas...). But you can reset your WP database (if you don't care about the content) using this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-reset/

That'll reset all your Wordpress, the database itself to the default Wordpress one. FTP will be untouched. So you'll still be able to use your theme, plugins and so on.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.  You say that the demo content is likely to be loaded remotely.  Does that mean that the theme author could have access to my database without me knowing?  If so, what measures could prevent this?